# Dynamics 365 Drag and Drop Attachment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

Is it possible to have a drag and drop interface for attachment in Dynamics 365 Portal?

Currently, I only found the solution for drag and drop attachment using web resource in the CRM Form but haven't found anything on portal.

Comment: As far as I know not natively.  You have to buy an add-on which enables it.  One example would be Document attacher from https://www.thrives.be/add-ons/document-attacher/.

Answer (score 0):

There are two supported ways to work with attachments on Portal:

1. Using Notes;
2. Integrating SharePoint

You can also render a HTML page on a Portal Entity Form if you want to put some more effort on this.